# Rstudio command history

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been using Rstudio a great deal these days but recently noticed that my commands are not being stored in the history any longer.  I don't know then this started, but it might have been with the install of the most recent version.  Any ideas on what the issue may be?

Thanks,

Comment: you better talk to the RStudio team directly about that, this seems hardly related to R.

Comment: I would surmise that that is a side-effect of using an entirely new UI ... rather than readline library common to R, bash, and a million other GNU packages.   As Joris says, open a ticket at rstudio.org and maybe they will add this.

Comment: Or use Emacs and always keep track of your history! =)

Comment: Right, or use a script file in RStudio and send the commands one by one.  That is *the* recommended way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug that we introduced in v0.93.73 and fixed in v0.93.75. Please try updating to the latest version at http://www.rstudio.org/download/desktop/.

Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 5):

If everything is normal (i.e., no bugs) there should be a checkbox under `Tools > Options > General` which says `Always save history (even when not saving .RData)`. This should be checked "Yes". Then look for the hidden file `.RHistory` in the present working directory and there your command history is.

(This comment is less for the OP than for a googler who stumbles across this question.)