# How to access the script/source history in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to access the history of what have been typed in the source panel in RStudio.

I'm interested in the way we learn and type code. Three things I would like to analyse are: i) the way a single person type code, ii) how different persons type code, iii) the way a beginner improve typing.

Grabbing the history of commands is quite satisfying as first attempt in this way but I would like to reach a finer granularity and thus access the successive changes, *within* a single line in a way.

So, to be clear, I'm neither looking for the [history of commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731230/rstudio-command-history) or for a diff between different versions of and `.R` file.

What I would like to access is really the successive alterations to the source panel that are visible when you recursively press `Ctrl+Z`. I do not know if there is a more accurate word for what I describe, but again what I'm interested in is how bits of code are added/moved/deleted/corrected/improved in the source panel but not necessary passed to the Console and thus absent from the history of command.

This must be somewhere/somehow saved by RStudio as it is accessible by the later. This may be saved in a quite hidden/private/memory/process/... way and I have a very vague idea of how a GUI works. I do not know it if would be easily accessible, then programmaticaly analyzed, typically if we could save a file from it. Timestamps would be the cherry on top but I would be happy without.

Do you have idea how to access this history?

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you looking for exactly. But if you are searching for history of typed commands, then in **RStudio** try 2 things:   **1.** shortcut key `Ctrl + 4` to put focus on history or `Ctrl+Shift+4` to enlarge window of history. `Ctrl+Atl+Shift+0` restores the default view.   **2.** place cursor in console and push Arrow Up (▲,↑) on your keyboard several times to find the command you typed.  Is it helpful?

Comment: RStudio save history of commands to `.Rhistory`. You can open it with text editor. But most probably you are searching for something more advanced.

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Vilmantas but that's not what I'm looking for. While programming in RStudio, if you press `Ctrl + Z`, you see the successive things added/moved/deleted (not necessary passed to the Console - so absent from the history of command) in the source panel. That's what I'm interested in. Plus I would need a way to access this history programmatically, eg from a file or equivalent.

Comment: Is this even expose as an api or file? I seriously doubt this. It could be expose only as api as I think IDE generally keep history (as list) in memory not disk. Not sure about RStudio but I doubt this could be done.

Comment: "Is this even expose as an api or file?" -> Does not seem to be exposed as a file. And I have no idea if the memory can be accessed or not.

Answer (score 4):

RStudio's source panel is essentially a view to an Ace Editor. As such you'd need to access the editor session's editSession and use getDocument or getWordRange along with the undo of the editSession's undoManager instance.

I don't think you'll be doing that from *within* RStudio without hacking on the RStudio code unless the RStudio Addin api is made to pass-thru editor events in the future.

It might be easier to write a session recorder as changes are made rather than try to mess with the undo history. I imagine you could write an Addin that calls a javascript to communicate over the existing RStudio port using the Ace Editor's events (ie. onChange).

Comment: I have no idea how to make it but thanks a bunch for the light in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

As @GegznaV said, RStudio saves code history to a ".RHistory" file. It's in the "Documents" folder on my computer. It's probably the same folder if you're using Windows. If you do not know the location, you can find the file by searching.

It also allows saving RStudio history to a file manually. There is a "Save" button in the History panel. So you can also get a timestamp. You can ask different users to save their code history after they have finished writing code. It may be indirectly useful to your research.

Comment: Hi! I was more looking for a "live" recording/access to what's typed in the console ;-)

Comment: Hi @VincentBonhomme, Sorry for not being able to help. I hope you can find the solution you are looking for. Good luck.